# How can I get JQuery to replace the non URL parts of the string when fetching the background images url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this code which extracts the element for the background image, however it pulls in the " url' " parts of the code too. I just need the actual image address

I have tried to use the replace function but it doesn't do anything to the string when i check the output.

```
var jsonData =
{ "image": jQuery('#block-content').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1'),
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'application/ld+json';
script.text = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
jQuery("head").append(script);
```

The image inside the element is //imageaddress.jpg so it's extracting it as

```
https://example.com/recipes/url(https://example.com/sites/image.jpg?itok=jfzYQHZx)
```

How can i fix this so that it just gives me

```
https://example.com/sites/image.jpg?itok=jfzYQHZx
```

Comment: `.+` matches any chars but line break chars, replace with  `[^()]+` to avoid matching parentheses. Better, use `[^()"']+`

Comment: Could you please post the content of `jQuery('#block-content').css('background-image')`

Comment: It looks like `<div class="intro-image media_27796" style="background-image: url('//example.com/sites/g/files/awvsbl221/files/styles/intro_homepage/public/image.jpg?h=c9aba1c0&amp;itok=siFmAXu7');">
  &nbsp;
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace image property with this

```
 "image": jQuery('#block-content').css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, ""),
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that some URLs are not always in the quotes:

```
url(https://example.com/sites/image.jpg?itok=jfzYQHZx)
```

Then add `['"]?` => `?` Detects zero or 1 char

```js
var str  = "url('https://example.com/sites/image.jpg?itok=jfzYQHZx')"; // example string
var str2 = "url(https://example.com/sites/image.jpg?itok=jfzYQHZx)"; // without quotes
str  = str.replace(/^url\(["']?(.+?)["']?\)/,"$1"); // replace with first group (.+?)
str2 = str2.replace(/^url\(["']?(.+?)["']?\)/,"$1"); 
console.log(str);
console.log(str2);
```

```
var jsonData = { "image": jQuery('#block-content').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(["']?(.+?)["']?\)/,"$1"),}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this help you.

```js
var tmp = 'https://example.com/recipes/url(https://example.com/sites/image.jpg?itok=jfzYQHZx)';
tmp = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf("(h") + 1);
tmp = tmp.substring(0, tmp.length - 1);
console.log(tmp);
```